# Is there any scripture that states Sanskrit is the mother of all languages?

Tags: scripture, sanskrit

Is there any Hindu scriptures that explicitly stated Sanskrit as the mother of all languages?

Comment: Does this ( https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/32365/is-sanskrit-really-the-mother-of-all-languages?newreg=a436cdc8f8894aaba1d2da0f1350eb10 ) answer our question

Comment: No. It is more of a linguistic take on whether Sanskrit is the mother of all languages or not. I want the scriptural basis for the belief amongst Hindus about Sanskrit being the mother of all languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [agni puraNa ch.337](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083567.html), sanskrit is the main language and all prakrits are its derivatives :

> *8. **Saṃskṛta (laṅguage) is for the gods and others**. There are three varieties of Prākṛta for men. Kāvya etc. are known to be of
> three kinds—prose, poetry and mixed.*