# If Sanskrit was spoken even by the Gods on Earth, how is Tamil older than Sanskrit?

Tags: history, language

Just to clarify, I'm not here to assert one language is older than the other. Based on popular articles, Tamil seems to be slightly older than Sanskrit, albeit it has been influenced by Sanskrit over the years.

Is the idea of Gods speaking Sanskrit just an assumption? Is there any reference in the Vedas about the Gods' language of choice?

P.S: I'm not looking for scientific evidence, but rather references of the languages our Gods spoke in our Vedas.

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question, but it's also probably off-topic given that scientific speculation isn't allowed on this site. Consider taking the [tour] :)

Comment: @CDR Thanks for the heads up. I'm aware that there's very little tangible / scientific evidence about which one's the oldest. (Hence why I was looking for references in the Vedas, not Science :))  I just wanted people's opinion on this topic. I can update the post to reflect that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any scripture that states Sanskrit is the mother of all languages?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54866/is-there-any-scripture-that-states-sanskrit-is-the-mother-of-all-languages)

Comment: "Tamil seems to be slightly older than Sanskrit" - this is based on archaeological surveys which can be proven wrong easily eg:  Take the case of taliban destroying buddha statue, 2000 years later when someone does an archaeological survey of afghan they will not find any remains of buddha statue there and arrive at a wrong finding that buddha statue never existed there. Thus archaeological survey don't qualify to be even  a valid "pratyaksha" and we have a "Śāstra pramāṇam" of sanskrit being eternal and mother of all.

Comment: The definition of god - brahman is that which is beyond birth and death in Hinduism. So it is very unlikely a god took birth and spoke anything (unlike Abrahamic religion). Most of the gods' real attributed experiences are mystical experiences, where these gods can come at any place, any time, and speak any language we understand arbitrarily. Specific incarnations of Vishnu/Shiva like Rama, Hanuman are well documented to speak languages of their particular age before renouncing materialistic plane.

Comment: Your new question works; I've retracted my close-vote.

Comment: "Is there any reference in the Vedas about the Gods' language of choice" - here is the reference in vedas https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53744/21696

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Yes, my bad. I actually meant, an avatar of God, such as Rama or Krishna.

Comment: @brahmāstra Yes, that's a good point. We had numerous invasions from the North destroying artifacts that would give us more material evidence. However, I'm not after material evidence, I'm looking for any evidence of avatars of Gods speaking Sanskrit from Vedas or any older scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
     FIGHTING OVER MYTH
```

The myth of Sanskrit as "coined language" has to be thrown from mind. There are more than 300 languages on Earth. All such 300 languages including Roman are ancient only.

```
  DHARMA CHAKRA & EVOLUTION
```

But Language of GODs & GODDESSES is Sanskrit only. Earthly languages have darker mix that can be easily corrupted by DEMONAIC spirits. Bad Spirits trying to inculcate multiple births due to accumulated sins.

```
 OTHER LANGUAGES CONSIDERED LOW
```

Example: an XXXX language spoken by humans can be decoded by demons far away by their dark powers of telepathy trying to invade the speaker for their interest as they cant be liberated from births & deaths.

To understand GOD -- in a language of mother tongue -- "SANSKRIT was interpreted" into local language by local language experts(Saints) to make others understand in their own languages. THERE IS ENOUGH FREEDOM OF SPEECH & EXPRESSION OF EMOTIONS in all local languages.

GOD's language of sanskrit is not meant for "free spoken words" but only to pray God through the same language gifted to humans by GOD.

```
ANCIENT & DERIVED/DEVELOPED languages
```

There are evidences of spoken sanskrit but the language is not sanskrit but its derivatives  ---)

Sindh :  (Punjabi, Urdu)

Hindh : (majority Inland Indian languages)

Gandarva: Malayala(Kerala), language similarity in Indian ocean  islands

Latin : (Luthesian, Arabic, Eurasian),

Angelian: (Western Roman, Greek)

Prakritam:  (Inter-Coastal languages : Telugu, Tamil, Bodhi-Malay-Mandarin, Polynesian(Aussie))

Gothic: (French, Catholic Russian)

Zend: (Afro asian & Sino mongolian),

Thorah: (Yehudis, Polish and Balkan Armenian), slovekian slang

ALL LANGUAGES are developed forms of the derivative languages as civilisation grew.

```
  NO OBSTACLE TO ANY LANGUAGE
```

Human groups can communicate between each other with more than 300 languages on Earth. There is no limitation in mixed languages spoken in India.

```
       ONLY CONDITION
```

"If you want GODS & GODESSES to help you, you must communicate in their language only. Their language is

"PRANAVAAKAARA SHABDHA RACHANA" - the vibrations that can travel beyond Earth's ionosphere termed as sanskrit. In sanskrit learning,  1st lesson is SHABDA that is not just singular-plural. It is the pronounciation.

GODS & GODDESSES are far from Earth. But we are gifted just their language(Sanskrit) to communicate to them through their DEITY in AALAYA.